# Android Espresso onData skipped

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-espresso

I am currently writing a test which uses the onData call to find and press a button.

```
public void testPickFavorites() throws InterruptedException {

        onData(anything())
                .inAdapterView(withId(android.R.id.list))
                .atPosition(0)
                .onChildView(withId(yesButtonId))
                .perform(click());
        onData(anything())
                .inAdapterView(withId(android.R.id.list))
                .atPosition(1)
                .onChildView(withId(noButtonId))
                .perform(click());

        onData(anything())
                .inAdapterView(withId(android.R.id.list))
                .atPosition(0)
                .onChildView(withId(maybeButtonId))
                .perform(click());
        onData(anything())
                .inAdapterView(withId(android.R.id.list))
                .atPosition(1)
                .onChildView(withId(maybeButtonId))
                .perform(click());
    }
```

The problem with this is that while certin test runs will perform all 4 clicks successfully, there are otheres where one or several of these clicks will not be performed. Does anyone know what's causing the issue?

Comment: Not be performed how? Exception? Or code runs, but you don't see any change?

Comment: I don't see the action (click) on device.

Comment: I did some digging and as it turns out, it was an asynchronous task that modifies the button on the list view. All I had to do was set a delay (Thread.sleep(500)) between each call in order to allow the asynchronous task to execute. I wouldn't recommend this, as a better solution would be to use Espresso's Idling Resources Api.